JasperSoft compatibility problems
I have a problem on my Jaspersoft Studio: I have intalled Jaspersoft® Studio Professional 8.2.0 - Visual Designer for JasperReports 6.20.3.
When I go into Windows>Preferences to set the compatibility , I see from the drop down list the reference to JasperReports versions 5.5.1 (marked as current),  5.2.0 and 5.1.0
I performed the same installation from the same installer of a colleage of mine and he can see from the drop down list lots of JR versions: from current (6.20) to older (the version needed for our project is 6.13)
I followed all the steps from this document, but didn't work (and actually I could not find the button with Add From URL option)
How can I solve?
Thanks in advance
Diego Polidori
I installed many times but always found the same problems. Followed the instructions reported in the Jasper community and forum (for example, this document )
I expect to find in the Windows->Preferences->Jaspersoft Studio Compatibility section the list of all the versions I need (from 6.x onwards)
